# how can I create the example module helloWorld in otrs 6

Tags: otrs

this is the link

https://doc.otrs.com/doc/manual/developer/stable/en/html/how-to-extend-otrs.html#writing-new-otrs-frontend-module

But I am so confuse about how to create a module helloWorld in otrs

One of the doubts that I have is

> "After creating the links and executing the Sysconfig, a new module with the name 'HelloWorld' is displayed. When calling it up, an error message is displayed as OTRS cannot find the matching frontend module yet. This is the next thing to be created. To do so, we create the following file...."

this "After creating the links and executing the Sysconfig" I don't know which links are they talking about.

I found this

https://doc.otrs.com/doc/manual/developer/stable/en/html/get-started.html#development-environment

that says

> "Linking Expansion Modules
> A clear separation between OTRS and the modules is necessary for proper developing. Particularly when using a git clone, a clear separation is crucial. In order to facilitate the OTRS access the files, links must be created. This is done by a script in the directory module tools repository. Example: Linking the Calendar Module:
>
> shell> ~/src/module-tools/link.pl ~/src/Calendar/ ~/src/otrs/
> "

the tools module is
git clone git@github.com:OTRS/module-tools.git

but the file called "link.pl" does not exists in the module tools, the docs does not say anything about this, nothing.

> "As soon as the linking is completed, the SysConfig must be rebuilt to register the module in OTRS. Additional SQL or Perl code from the module must also be executed. Example:
> ~/src/module-tools/DatabaseInstall.pl -m Calendar.sopm -a install"

how they get ".sopm extension? they does not say anything

I am using centos 7, I installed otrs using this guide

http://doc.otrs.com/doc/manual/admin/stable/en/html/installation.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems that people responsible for OTRS did not bother updating their developer documentation - information there is outdated. I have just started messing around with OTRS development and faced the exact same problem.

To answer your questions:

1. There is no **link.pl** file because module-tools has been updated to accommodate all of the separate helper files into a single one (**otrs.ModuleTools.pl**). You can create a link using:

   `otrs.ModuleTools.pl Module::File::Link`
2. 'Executing SysConfig' means re-building system configuration files described in [developer manual first chapter, 'Linking Expansion Modules' section](https://doc.otrs.com/doc/manual/developer/stable/en/html/get-started.html#environment-link-modules).
   You can do that with OTRS' command line helper otrs.Console.pl located at `/otrs/bin/` like so:

   `/opt/otrs/bin/otrs.Console.pl Maint::Config::Rebuild`